# Getting a pointer to event target within UIGestureRecognizer event handler

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, event-handling

Suppose I have an event handler that handles tap events:

```
-(void) handleOptionTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        UIView* target = recognizer.view;
    }
}
```

I'm able to get a pointer to the `UIView` object that was tapped via the `view` property of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance.  The problem is that I only have access to it via a base class `UIView` pointer.  If the target is a subclass, such as a `UILabel`, how can I access the view via a subclass pointer so that I can do *specific* things with the label (like for example change the text color or whatever.)

Should I just downcast here, if I know that the `UIView` instance definitely **[IS A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)** `UILabel`?

Comment: Yes, just cast if you know for sure the view is some specific subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you sure view is UILabel class use:

```
UILabel* target = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
```

if you not sure than you can check it

```
if ([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
    UILabel* target = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
}
```